# Repeat echo while answer is No

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, while-loop

I am very new to Bash scripting, so please excuse me if the question is somewhat incoherent.

I want my script to repeat a question 4 times if the user answers No, if the user answers Yes, then the script can exit, this is what I have so far

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Would you like a cup of tea?"

read answer

while true;

do

        if [ $answer = Y ] then
        echo "Great, I'll make tea now"; then
                break
        if [ $answer = N ] then
        echo "Are you sure?"
        continue
        if [ $answer = N ] then
        echo "Are you sure?"
        continue
        if [ $answer = N ] then
        echo "Are you sure?"
        continue
        if [ $answer = N ] then
        echo "Ok, I give up!"
        exit
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things you need to fix in your code. I highly recommend you going through basic tutorial before you continue.

Anyway, the very basic program you can do is something like:

```
count=0
while true;
do
    read -r answer
    if [ "$answer" = "Y" ]; then
        echo "Great, I'll make tea now"
        break
    fi
    if [ "$answer" = "N" ]; then
        echo "Are you sure?"
        count=$((count+1))
        if [ $count = 4 ]; then
            break
        fi
    fi
done
```

We set `count` to be the number of times the user provides "N" as an answer, and we check when it reaches 4, and break.

Comment: Thanks for your help Maroun, I spent 3 days working on it before I reached out for assistance. I need to work on how to articulate what I want the code to do. Thanks again

Comment: @GerryH You're welcome. Please make sure you understand the solution and let me know if you have any problems.